# Excel 2007 ,VBA form to filter worksheet records based on condition

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have a list of records that I want to work with it through VBA form.

for ex: below records list

```
ID          Score   Date  
------------------------------
228483      80      5/10/2011  
243216      60      4/3/2011  
285483      40      5/1/2011  
291584      30      5/2/2011  
291323      70      4/4/2011  
285607      40      5/7/2011  
7158441     90      5/8/2011  
7083234     10      4/2/2011
```

I would like to have a vba form having multi form components which each will list the records from this above list based on condition.

for example on the top left the component will list records who scored over 50, and on the top right another component from the same type will list records achieved during month# 5.

I 'm not that much in VBA forms and really don't know what component will do that and how.

Will any changes in the worksheet be reflected directly to the lists in the vba form?

---

Thanks brother Jonsca and harag for the great support and yes I'm looking something like DataGridView that is a scrollable and sortable table retreived from database based on condition..I tried to look for "Microsoft Office Spreadsheet" but it seems it need some work around for excel2007 to add it but my question is , could we have this in simpler way for example a local web page could be connected to excel sheet and have the same control in it....I made a sketch for what i'm looking for

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3834/13125375.png

Is it easier to build a danamic connection between web page to worksheet (and with having this control)...big thanks brothers in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you don't know about the forms and you have to work with them, you should spend time understanding how they work before you take on a project with them.

Comment: could you please tell me what component does that, I tried vba controls but I don't get the control that display records in the form...I'm good little bit in vba but not in forms and I tried but still don't get it and no body to ask around so could you please assist?

Comment: I just need at least the control name or component name which display worksheet records inside form based on condition,,at least the name :|

Comment: there is listbox, comdobox and refedit but these display one cell a time or one two colomns but I need a component that displays multi colomns and row (records) which meet the condition.

Comment: Probably a textbox would be your best bet.  See [this](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=362)(the lower half) to get a quick jump start.  For your purposes, you will probably need to adjust the multiline and locked properties (accessible in the Properties box on the left hand side of the IDE) to true (locked will prevent the user from editing the data, but will still allow copy).

Comment: Sorry, our posts crossed.  Well, sounds like you need something like a DataGridView that .NET offers, but you won't be able to use that using VBA, I don't believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a listbox control. The listbox can display several columns, you just need to populate it. Something like the below should help

```
'clear the listbox
lst.Clear

' set the number of columns
lst.ColumnCount = 5

' iterate through the cells and populate the listbox
For x = 1 to 10
    With lst
        .AddItem "ID"                       ' Column 1 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Score"  ' Column 2 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Date"   ' Column 3 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Col 4"  ' Column 4 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = "Col 5"  ' Column 5 data
        'etc.
    End With
Next

' set the widths of the columns
lst.ColumnWidths = "2.0cm;1.0cm;2.0cm;1.0cm;1.0cm"
```

You will need to pull in the values you want accordingly

Hope this helps

EDIT:
**>>Will any changes in the worksheet be reflected directly to the lists in the vba form?<<**
No, you will need to update the listbox through VBA code.

Comment: Actually it's something like what circled in red in the picture that should be tied to the data in the sheet but this is from acces and I don't know if excel has it?! and I don't know the name of this component. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/captureqwv.jpg/

Comment: It's a componant that displays many records programatically (under conditions) and I could scroll through and sort..sorry that my reviews are messy too much

Comment: Sorry I don't see any picture in your post so not sure what is circled in red.

Comment: i don't know the problem as it's ok with me and the link is ... http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/captureqwv.jpg/

Comment: In the form design window, rightclick on the toolbox and add new controls. Search the list for something like "Microsoft Office Spreadsheet", this will basically put a spreadsheet on the form which you could use. I've personally never used this myself.